# $$< in secondary expansion of implicit rules seems to be wrong - what am I missing?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

It appears that `$$<` in secondary prerequisite expansion for implicit rules, evaluates to the target, not, as I would expect from the manual, the first prerequisite already assigned.  What am I missing?

```
> cat Makefile
.SECONDEXPANSION:

foobar%: prereq% $$<1
    @echo prereqs: $^
    touch $@ 

>touch foobar01 prereq0 prereq01
>make foobar0
prereqs: prereq0 foobar01
touch foobar0
```

From the manual, the prerequisites should be `prereq0 prereq01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a real bug... or something.  See https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?28456

This is tricky because at the time make is performing the second expansion it doesn't know what the value of `$<` is yet.  It would need to go through the prerequisite list and, rather than expanding everything at once, do the expansion word by word to ensure that the automatic variables come into existence as soon as possible.

Do-able, but not trivial.  Anyway.  It doesn't work correctly now obviously.

Comment: Well, I was actually surprised to see this in the manual.  I thought, "if this kind of thing works, it is probably undocumented".